# What are the solid chunks in the top my carrots?

Tags: carrots

I've been getting through my home-grown carrots lately. I've had a few raw, and twice now I've noticed solid chunks in the top of the carrot. The first time when my teeth crunched on it I figured it was a piece of plastic the carrot had grown around. It was a piece about 5mm², solid, and a translucent whitish colour.

It happened again just now, so I'm thinking maybe it's not plastic. And if it's not, then what else might it be? Some kind of crystallization?

Comment: Very strange.  Can you post or link to a picture maybe?

Comment: I think you were right the first time - maybe not plastic, but some things that were in/on the ground.

Answer (score 4):

If the carrots were left in the ground for too long, a hard stalk starts forming and as you mentioned it isn't very good to eat. Next time try to check one before buying a bunch.

Comment: The hard stalk is not like the thing the OP described. It feels like wood, not like plastic, and is not translucent.